# Почему при срабатываниии хендлера вызывается render-метод трижды?

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui

Работаю с [этой библиотекой](https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/checkbox) и хочу сделать список с итемами, у каждого из которых будет чекбокс. Мой код:

```
import React, { Component }            from 'react'
import { Divider,Label,List,Checkbox,Header } from 'semantic-ui-react'


export default class Menu extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            checkboxes: []
        }
    }

    render() {
        let { tags } = this.props;
        return (
            <div className="ui segment basic " >
                {typeof tags === "undefined" ?
                    <div>Select partner and process</div>
                :
                    this.getTagListItems()
                }
            </div>
        )
    }

    getTagListItems = () => {
        let { tags } = this.props;

        let tagsGroup = [];
        for(let i=0; i<tags.length; i++){
            if ( tags[i].children.length !==0 ) {
                tagsGroup.push(
                    <div className="container"  key = { i }>
                        <Header as="h3">{ tags[i].name }</Header>
                        <Divider/>
                        <List>
                            { this.getTagCheckboxes(tags[i].children) }
                        </List>
                    </div>
                );
            }
        }
        return tagsGroup;
    };

    getTagCheckboxes = checkboxData => {
        let checkboxes = [];
        for(let i=0; i<checkboxData.length; i++) {
            checkboxes.push(
                <List.Item key = { checkboxData[i].id }>
                    <Checkbox label   = { checkboxData[i].name }
                              id      = { checkboxData[i].id }
                              onClick = { this.setTag }                            
                    />
                    <List.Content floated="right" >
                        <Label>
                            0
                        </Label>
                    </List.Content>
                </List.Item>
            );
        }
        return checkboxes;
    };

    setTag = (e, itemData) => {
        let { checkboxes } = this.state;
        console.log('ITEMM!!!', itemData)

    }

}
```

Все рендерится, однако при клике на чекбокс `setTag` вызывает render  трижды. Почему это происходит? Как это можно исправить?

Comment: Скорее всего вам нужно использовать onChange

Comment: @DanielKhoroshko действительно.  с onChange  он срабатывает как положено. у меня есть вопрос и просьба. вопрос: почему эти 2 события срабатывают по-разному? просьба: продублируйте пожалуйста комментарий в ответ,чтобы я его выбрал и закрыл вопрос.спасибо

Comment: да вот я ответил , спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Приветствую!

1) Чтобы отслеживать состояние чекбокса в semantic-ui-react стоит использовать событие `onChange`:

> Called when the user attempts to change the checked state.

2) А чтобы выяснить, почему обработчик события `onClick` вызывается несколько раз, можно посмотреть чему равно event.target у события, вероятно оно вызывается и для чекбокса и для лэйбла и для ещё какого-нибудь элемента

```
Called when the checkbox or label is clicked.
```

Другой путь узнать что происходит под капотом - глянуть в сорцах. https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI-React/blob/master/src/modules/Checkbox/Checkbox.js , в самом конце фактически событие будет вызвано из-за каждой из строчек 245, 255 и 266 (педположительно)